# Issue with waiting for dispatch to complete before running the next function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a function **onPressItem** in a React Native component that dispatches an action using **Redux**, and then navigates to another screen using **pushScreenOnFormScreen**. I want to ensure that the **dispatch** action **(FormActionLoadFormData)** is completed before executing the **pushScreenOnFormScreen** function. I have tried using **await** with **async** on the **onPressItem** function, but it's giving me the error **"'await' has no effect on the type of this expression."** I've also attempted using **useEffect**, but it causes the **pushScreenOnFormScreen** function to be executed multiple times, leading to a navigation stack screen with the same **id error/warning.**

```
const onPressItem = async (formData: any) => {
setFormData(formData);
dispatch(FormActionLoadFormData(formData));

pushScreenOnFormScreen({
componentId: Screens.FORM_FIELDS_SCREEN,
passProps: { formData: formData, formFields: formFields },
});
};
```

What would be the correct way to wait for the dispatch to complete before moving on to the next function in this scenario? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edited:
This is **FormActionLoadFormData**

```
function* FormSagaLoadFormData({
                             payload,
                           }: FormTypeLoadFormData): 
 Generator<ReturnYield> {
 try {
  // Getting the auth token from store.
 const token: any = yield select(userSelectorAuthenticationToken);

// Here the payload is just the { id: 00, name: '', ... }.
// @ts-ignore
const id: number = payload ? (payload.id ? payload.id : -1) : -1;
const result: any = yield call(ApiGetFormByID, {token, id});

let form: any = null;
try {
  form = result.data.data.form;
} catch (err) {
  //
}

if (form) {
  yield put({
    type: FORM_ACTION.REDUCER.SAVE_FORM_DATA,
    payload: form,
  });
}
 } catch (error) {
  console.log('FormSagaLoadFormData error', error);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Redux actions are typically synchronous so there's nothing to wait for. If you are using ***asynchronous*** actions and have the appropriate middleware integrated, then you can `await` the actions to resolve if they return promises. Can you [edit] to share a bit more how you have configured the redux store so we can see how it possibly handles asynchronous actions, and the `FormActionLoadFormData` action code you want to wait for?

Comment: thank you, I have added FormActionLoadFormData code

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting API, the correct way to handle this would be to check whether the call is successful or not. The best practice is to have a [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020089/how-to-know-an-asynchronous-call-has-finished-with-redux-saga) action which will be dispatched on api call succeeding.

Then in the react component where you want to dispatch the action after it is completed, you will do

```
const isSuccess = useSelector(success);

const onPressItem = async (formData: any) => {
  setFormData(formData);
  dispatch(FormActionLoadFormData(formData));
}



useEffect(()=>{
            pushScreenOnFormScreen({
             componentId: Screens.FORM_FIELDS_SCREEN,
             passProps: { formData: formData, formFields: formFields },
  });
  },[success])
```